# QFT Fields or Energy Mesh

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy, vacuum

I'm not a mathematician, but I've read alot about QFT theory.  The way it is visualized are different levels of energy and the fields interacting with one another.  Am I correct that these fields overlap each other in the same point in space?  What if each point in space has exactly the same amount of energy, and in order to create higher levels of energy, that energy has to be drawn from the points around it which would pull and twist space as it absorbs the surrounding energy to produce the known subparticles.  Do we consider QFT fields as more energy in a single space?  Or do we consider each field as just a description of a higher energy state?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to understand quantum fields.  Are the just different levels of energy which represent the different particles?  Where do they get their energy from to occupy that particular point in space if energy is finite?  All matter is energy and energy is conserved.  So in the initial state of the universe at the point of the big bang was enegry equally dispersed.  Is energy via matter moving through space and occupying empty space void of energy, or is matter when it moves utilizing the new energy in its new position in space?

Comment: I guess I'm imagining space as points of energy with a finite amount at each point and in order to move to a higher level its needs the surrounding points to achieve higher energy levels.  When it absorbs that energy it pulls on the space around as energy moves to occupy that space

Comment: Comments can’t clarify a question, because they are never considered part of the question. To clarify a question, you must *edit* it.

Comment: Please be aware that quantum field theory is one of the most complicated areas of theoretical physics. It relies heavily on mathematics and isn’t easy to describe in words. Quantum field theory does *not* involve pulling and twisting space; spacetime curvature is part of General Relativity, which is *not* a quantum field theory.

Comment: I get that QFT is visualized as fields & grids that interact with each other, and i understand  that QFT does not twist space.  Every diagram of QFT shows a layered levels of fields that interact with each other transferring energy & momentum between them.  However, my question is the quarumn fields require energy & is that energy just being transferred from other points in space or when matter moves through space are we using the zero point energy at that point in space.  A photon traveling through space is a electromagnetic wave and is that wave propagating momentum between points in space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the quantum field is not described by quantized energy levels at every point is space. The energy is not localized at points. Instead, to get the total energy of a quantum state, one needs to integrate the modulus square of its wave function over all space. For example, the wave function of a single particle (one quantum of a field) would in general be spread out over a finite region of space.

Quantum field theory is more about the dynamics than about the states. It is described in terms of point interactions among the wave functions of the different fields that interact. Each point interaction is integrated over all points to get a finite probability amplitude for the interaction. During such an interaction, each field contributes or receives a quantum of that field. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you this is a very good description!!!  Answered my question.